# wp_query 's', search filter with pagination is not working

Tags: wp-query, filters, pagination, search

I made this shortcode for a page of posts.
I want to set a search function.
I filled for example: "web design".
The search-result will set in the var "$catSearched". Then it works how i want.
But! when i click the next page, it doesn't get the variable $catSearched.
For example:
when i clikck next button(a href), then i lost the result in https://www.myexampledomain.com/postpages/page/2

Because, of course the var $catSearched will reset, when i move to another page.
How can i keep the search result..!?

Here is my codes:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { 
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}


if ( isset($_POST['submit_search']) ) :
    if ( !empty($_POST['input_search']) ) : 
        $catSearched =  $_POST['input_search'];
    endif; 
endif;



$html .= '<form method=\'POST\'>';
$html .= '<label>Search here: </label>';
$html .= '<input type=\'text\' name=\'input_search\' />';
$html .= '<button id=\'cat--submit\' type=\'submit\' name=\'submit_search\' value=\'Submit\' />It is Btn</button>';
$html .= '</form>';


$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    's' => $catSearched,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date'
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$html .= '<ul>';
if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $html .= '<li>';
        $html .= '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
        $html .= '</li>';
    endwhile;
$html .= '</ul>';

    $pageAll = $my_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($pageAll > 1) :
        $orig_query = $wp_query; // fix for pagination to work
        $wp_query = $my_query;

        // PREV
        $prevBtn = get_previous_posts_link( 'Prev' )

        // NEXT
        $nextBtn = get_next_posts_link( 'Next', $pageAll )
                    
        $html .= '<nav>';
        $html .= '<span class=\'prev\'>'. $prevBtn .'</span>';
        $html .= '<span class=\'next\'>'. $nextBtn .'</span>';
        $html .= '</nav>';

        $wp_query = $orig_query;
    endif;


    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;


return $html;
```

Comment: You can attempt to pass the value through your next page URL as a GET parameter, but that means you'll have to take the extra steps of modifying your pagination links to include that kind of parameter. something like "?q=input_search_val" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652605/extracting-a-parameter-from-a-url-in-wordpress

Comment: the pagination functions use the main query, if you want them to use your shortcodes query you will need to modify them, but if the original page and query don't have a page 2 then it will fail unless you use separate pagination parameters in your next/previous page URLs, and the search term, `get_previous_posts_link` etc on their own aren't enough. If you want to change the posts that WP shows, the proper method is to modify the main query with `pre_get_posts` instead of creating a new second query, and a shortcode is not a great way to do that